# How to use exclusion constraints with Postgres BDR

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-bdr

Looks like [BDR doesn't support exclusion constraints](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/bdr/latest/conflicts/#exclusion-constraint-conflicts)...

However, I'm using exclusion constraints to achieve the same result as a unique constraint (but using a hash index instead of a B-Tree):

```
alter table my_table add constraint my_table_unique_hash exclude using hash (my_unique_field with =);
```

Can I tell BDR to consider the exclusion constraint only for the master and ignore it in the read replicas?

Comment: If you have "master" and "read replicas", you probably shouldn't be using BDR.

Comment: If you only ever have a single writeable node, the risk of synchronisation deadlocks is zero, so you should be OK with not deleting the exclusion constraint. May be you could clarify what problem you have exactly?